# Use variable in SQL query

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, variables, psycopg2

I want to create a variable `now` that is set to the current time, and then use it in my psycopg2 queries. I've tried using python's `datetime` as well as `current_timestamp`, in the following way but it produces an error and can't recognize the variable:

```
@app.route('/_ajax', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def userCount():
    now = current_timestamp
    cur.execute("""SELECT count(DISTINCT(username)) from user_table WHERE tstampz >
                   (now - INTERVAL '60 mins')""")
    userCount=cur.fetchone()[0]
    return jsonify (userCount=userCount)
```

If I use `datetime.datetime.now` instead of `current_timestamp` an error reports that `datetime` cannot be indexed. How can I set this variable properly?

To clarify: The reason why I do not want to use `current_timestamp` or 'now()` directly in the query is because the time will **default** to the current time, but it will be changed at some point (based on user input), therefore changing the query.

Comment: You need to set correct date format

Comment: just use `now()` instead of `now` in query?.. I dont think mixing database server time and client time in ajax is a good idea at all

Comment: You aren't using the Python variable `now`; you are using a (nonexistant) SQL column name. Check your DB library to see how to create a parameterized SQL query.

Comment: @VaoTsun I realize that works within the query (just like using `current_timestamp` works, but I wanted a variable in order to change it dynamically

Comment: you mean injecting the actual value instead of `now`?..

Comment: @VaoTsun I want to know if it's possible to put a variable in place of `now()`. The default should be set to the current time, but this value should be changed based on a user input, so it needs to be a variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this in Python, you need a parameterized query. (Check your documentation for details; you may need something slightly different from what I show.)

```
@app.route('/_ajax', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def userCount():
    now = datetime.now()
    cur.execute("""SELECT count(DISTINCT(username)) from user_table WHERE tstampz >
                   (%s - INTERVAL '60 mins')""", (now,))
    userCount=cur.fetchone()[0]
    return jsonify (userCount=userCount)
```

Comment: Thanks, I used the parameterized part of your answer! I set `now` = `datetime.now()` instead but otherwise this works. I don't know why I tried `datetime.datetime.now()` the first time, was a silly mistake

Comment: Your confusion is understandable: `now()` is a classmethod of the `datetime.datetime` class. If you `import datetime` then you need `datetime.datetime.now()`. But if you use `from datetime import datetime` you need `datetime.now()`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer you accepted shows a correctly-parameterized query. You should note, however, that PostgreSQL knows what the current time is, and you run the risk of time zone confusion by using the time from the client. If you really need rows from the last hour a safer query is

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT(username)) from user_table WHERE tstampz >
               (current_timestamp - INTERVAL '60 mins')
```

Somewhat oddly, [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-datetime.html) lists `current_datetime` as a function, but you will find if you add the parentheses to call it you get a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

I think the query should be:

```
SELECT count(DISTINCT username)
from user_table
WHERE tstampz > (now() - INTERVAL '60 mins')
```

Note that `now()` is a function not a "variable" in Postgres.

Comment: I understand that works (so does using `current_timestamp` directly in the query) but it's not what I'm looking for. I need to set a variable that can be changed, and is not always necessarily the current time.